# ViewModel doesn't receive message in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have two ViewModels: MainViewModel and QuestionViewModel. I Register they in ViewModelLocator.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<QuestionViewModel>();
```

On MainViewModel I have a ListBox with Questions. When Click I execute this command

```
NavigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri("/Pages/QuestionPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
Messenger.Default.Send<Question, QuestionViewModel>(q);
```

QuestionPage's DataContext set to QuestionViewModel. On QuestionViewModel I register message:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<Question>(this, q =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("!");
});
```

But this function work only on second open of QuestionViewModel, because QuestionViewModel instance creates only on first opening. My Question is: Where and When I need to create instance of QuestionViewModel in MVVM Light? I dont want create all my pages at startup.

Now, I create instance in constructor ViewModelLocator:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<QuestionViewModel>();
}
```

It is good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, this is not a good practice to create all view models in `ViewModelLocator` constructor. The reason of the issue you got is that `QuestionViewModel` is created after you send the message. You can try to create a service which will share current `Question` object and inject this service into `MainViewModel` and `QuestionViewModel`.

```
public interface IQuestionService
{
    Question CurrentQuestion {get; set;}
}

public class QuestionService : IQuestionService
{
    public Question CurrentQuestion {get; set;}
}
```

Then on `Click` in `MainViewModel` just save current question:

```
_questionService.CurrentQuestion = q;
```

and use in in your `QuestionViewModel`

Just make sure you inject the same instance of IQuestionService into your view models.

One more variant is to pass simple navigation arguments in a URL like this:

```
NavigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri("/Pages/QuestionPage.xaml?questionid=" + q.Id, UriKind.Relative));
```

Alternatively, you could try to implement your own NavigationService which supports passing parameters, but this is more complicated.